# C++ overloading single operator passing 2 structures as pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading, structure, operator-keyword

Ok. I have the structure:

```
struct birthdayPerson
{
    int day, month, year;
    public:
        void Show()
        {
            std::cout << day << " " << month << " " << year << std::endl;
        }
};
```

Then i want to overload the "==" so it can compare 2 instateated structs if those people has the same birthday (day and month). I have a 2 element array pointer of this struct:

```
birthdayPerson * personBirth[2];
personBirth[0] = new birthdayPerson;
personBirth[1] = new birthdayPerson;
```

Then i overload like this:

```
bool operator==(birthdayPerson person1, birthdayPerson person2)
{
    return (person1.day == person2.day &&
    person1.month == person2.month);
}
```

And finally i use in the code:

```
bool sameBirthDay = personBirth[0] == personBirth[1];
```

But, why it doesn't call the "overladed" function (operator)?. 
What am i doing worong?

Comment: Because you compare pointers. These are built-in types so they cannot have user-defined overloaded operators.

Comment: Why are you using pointers?  Why are you using `new`?

Comment: @MooingDuck i'm using pointers becouse i need on the fly creating >1 people and i want to check it those all people created has the same randomly generated Birthday

Comment: Sounds like a case for `std::vector` or `std::array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your `operator==` should take its parameters by const reference:

`bool operator==(const birthdayPerson &person1, const birthdayPerson &person2)`

Second, your array contains `birthdayPerson*` *pointers*, not actual `birthdayPerson` *objects*.  Your statement `personBirth[0] == personBirth[1]` is comparing pointers, which is why your operator is not invoked.  You need to deference the pointers to compare the objects properly:

```
bool sameBirthDay = *(personBirth[0]) == *(personBirth[1]);
```

Otherwise, change the array to hold objects, rather than pointers to objects:

```
birthdayPerson personBirth[2];
...
bool sameBirthDay = personBirth[0] == personBirth[1];
```

Comment: Very acertive and clear answer. Thanks @Remy very much.

Answer (score 3):

`personBirth` is an array of `BirthdayPerson*`. You need to dereference pointers to compare the objects they are pointing to:

```
bool sameBirthDay = *personBirth[0] == *personBirth[1];
```

Otherwise you are comparing 2 pointers, which is not the same thing. (and also the reason it doesn't call your `operator==` on `birthdayPerson`).

Also, I can't see any reason why you are using pointers at all in this code. You could just create objects instead. If you want a collection of objects, use `std::vector`, or if you know the number of objects you need at compile time, you can use `std::array`.

This is not related to your question, but as @RemyLebeau points out in their answer, your `operator==` is not idiomatic. The signature should instead be:

```
bool operator==(birthdayPerson const &person1, birthdayPerson const &person2);
```

Otherwise you are making needless copies of the objects you're comparing.

Answer (score -2):

Do you initiate them ? If not it fails. You do not have a default value.

```
bool operator==(birthdayPerson person1, birthdayPerson person2)
{
    std:: cout << person1.day <<" "<<person2.day<<"\n";
    return (person1.day == person2.day &&
    person1.month == person2.month);
}
```

if no initiated:

```
4196144 32766
```

If you compare the pointers, you dont call the overloaded function. Comparing the addresses. Again fail.

Comment: What you say about the initial values is true, but has no bearing on the OP's *actual* question about why the overloaded `operator==` is not being called.